# Strange preg_replace escaping?

Tags: php, escaping, preg-match

I am just wordering how to solve this.

I have this code

```
<?php
$test = "\u0000hi";
preg_match("|\\\\u0000|", $test, $a);
print_r($a);
?>
```

in above case, it works. however, I do not know why should I use too many escaping characters?

in below case

```
<?php
$test = "\\u0000hi";
preg_match("|\\\\\\\\u0000|", $test, $a);
print_r($a);
?>
```

I do have 8 escape characters `\` in `preg_match` and two in `$test` variable (double count as in previous example)

Could someone explain me this begginer problem ?

Comment: When in doubt you can always use `preg_quote()` to escape your strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to find one backslash `'\u'`

you need to escape it in your  regex `'/\\u/'`

and if you put your regex in double-quotes you need to escape both backslashes b/c otherwise they are evaluated as one backslash in your string and then as a meta-char in your regex:

```
"/\\\\u/"
```

at the top I wrote '\u' instead of "\u" like inyour case, b/c actually if \u is a control-char in "\u" then you won't find any backslash anyway.

Comment: so tell me, how should it look like when I would like to find two \\ ?

Comment: whoops. I forgot that $test is being escaped too.

Answer (score 1):

Both `$test` string notations evaluate to the same string internally. Try it yourself:

```
var_dump("\u0000hi");
// Outputs string(8) "\u0000hi"

var_dump("\\u0000hi");
//Outputs string(8) "\u0000hi"
```

Same original string, so you need the same regex to match it. That's the one with four `\` in it.

Comment: [I opened new question for it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731660/strange-preg-quote-behavior) because I have no idea, WHY