# strange preg_quote behavior

Tags: php, escaping, behavior

I have this code

```
<?php
$a = "\\u0000";
$b =  preg_quote($a);
echo "<br />my own: ".$a;
echo "<br />with preg_quote:". $b;
?>
```

[result is here](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/88dc0.php)

How is possible that one `\` character vanished from my `$a` variable?

I think it's very begginer behavior/question but I'm really lost about these escape characters.

Disclaimer: I'm not begginer in PHP

Comment: How can you be "not a beginner in PHP" while you don't know how PHP strings work? \*scratches head\*

Comment: I know this will show \ and in this case I know why (because you would get parse error with single one)

Comment: _because you would get parse error with single one_ - it's the final result you get, not the answer to the question **why** :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because `\` escapes the next one, as every `\` needs to be escaped.

with a single \ it escapes the next character witch is u, but \u isn't a char code so it is displayed like a simple character

Comment: with a single ``\`` it escapes the next character witch is ``u``, but ``\u`` isn't a char code so it is displayed like a simple character

Comment: escaping is not necessarily but possibly. Some time it's necessarily.(e.g. "\\n" to "\n" not EOLN)

Comment: so no matter if that escapes next character, but it just "excepts" character such as n (new line)...

Comment: what you write is confusing and weird. and why are you editing mihai lorgas answer?

Answer (score 1):

because `\` does have a meaning in string.

i.e. `\n` is the char code for a new line

so `\\` is the escaped version of a backslash and evaluates to `\`

Answer (score 1):

```
$a="\\";
```

// `$a` is `\` now, because first `\` escape another `\`

all is OK

Answer (score 1):

in $a the double-backslash is evalutated as an escaped backslash, leads to one backslash in output.

in $b preg_quote will escape both backslashes as they are regex-meta-characters. leads to four backslashes in a row, leads to two backslashes in your output.

Answer (score 1):

`\\` is the escaped version of `\`. So, the original string, when printed, only displays a single `\`. However, `preg_quote` escapes the `\` character with another `\` and thereby results in `\\`.